# How to create tls certs which I can use in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, keycloak

I'm facing a trouble that I need certs for my Keycloak inside k8s cluster to use nginx ingress. Which is the easiest way to add them?
I started like this:

```
kubectl create secret tls tls-keycloak-ingress --cert=localtest.me.crt --key=localtest.me.pem
```

And then include them via secret in Chart yaml:

```
 ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    path: /auth/?(.*)
    hosts:
      - keycloak.localtest.me
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - keycloak.localtest.me
        secretName: tls-keycloak-ingress
```

But should I create them on host machine? Or with kubectl somehow?

Comment: I couldn't get you. If you do the above two steps, TLS should work

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian sure it will, I just needed to find a wasy to create certs inside k8s, the answear below helped me, i gues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically solved by adding a cert-manager into the cluster. It then tracks all ingress objects `tls` sections and issues using the provided LE account:

https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/

It's not only issues and stores cert to an appropriate secret, but also renews automatically.

NOTE: if you are using helm3 skip tiller step.

Comment: Added small example here with cer-manager, could you please give smal review? Thank you https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/kubernetes-keycloak/tree/master/kubernetes

Comment: `kind: Certificate` will be created automatically from the ingress object once you deploy cert-manager. `ClusterIssuer` is cluster-wide, you may want to put it outside of KC repo cause it's reused by other apps.